Cant see the values in a Toasted Kotlin Integer array
So I have defined a simple Integer Array in Kotlin (in activity 1)
 var arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

The following Toast allows me to see the values in the array (in activity 1) as [1,2,3,4,5]
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Array = " + arr.contentToString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I then pass the array to a second activity using
  val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
           
            intent.putExtra("key4", arr)

 startActivity(intent)

In activity 2 I use the following to get the array
  val newArr = intent ( "key4" )

Here I did try
 val newArr = intent .getSerializableExtra( "key4" )

But Android Studio Koala struck-out the .getSerializableExtra
Now I am trying to see the values using
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Array now = " + newArr.contentToString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

But my output is
[!@c1b80a4] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]

Could someone please explain what I have done wrong ?

OK ! I have solved it ! I defined the Integer Array as an ArrayList and successfully passed that.

getSerializableExtra with single parameter is deprecated, which returns Serializable.
Instead use getSerializableExtra("key4", IntArray::class.java) that will return the value of an item previously added
